# AFNetworking Crash: [AFURLConnectionOperation networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:]

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am not able to reproduce this crash which is reported by crashlytic 2 times, Just tried enough googling up to find the cause and solution to this but hard luck.

Can some one help me understand the cause and solution to this.

[image: This is what is get on crashlytic]